# Get data from database in Custom ListView Using Base Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview

Hi I'm new to stackoverflow and java too. Can someone help in solving the issue that I'm facing when I display data in listview. ListView shows record like : com.example.ayeshanaeem.addviewdata.Record@72d730
follwing is code: ViewListContents.java

```
public class ViewListContents extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper myDB;
private ClipData myClip;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewcontents_layout);


    final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);


    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    final ArrayList<Record> theList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data = myDB.getAllData();
    if(data.getCount() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(ViewListContents.this, "The Database was empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        while(data.moveToNext()){
            Record r=new Record();
            r.setRecordRollno(data.getString(1));
            r.setRecordName(data.getString(2));
            theList.add(r);
            ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, theList);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    }
    //To copy text of item on click in listview
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            String getstring = theList.get(i).toString();
            myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text",getstring);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Text copied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
}
```

I have made Record.java + RecordAdapter.java + MainActivity.java too
This is DatabaseHelper.java

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, RollNo TEXT, NAME TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String rollno,String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,rollno);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,name);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
    return res;
}

}
```

Comment: http://abhiandroid.com/ui/baseadapter-tutorial-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Use viewholder pattern and make a custom view to draw each row for your listview.

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Also you should use Realm to an alternative database to manage your information through objects.

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest